# Rails 3 routing inside a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have just switched to rails from padrino/sinatra so the routing stuff puzzles me.

I have defined,

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :teachers, :students, :lessons
  end
```

in my routes.rb file, and when i run rake routes command it gives me,

```
    admin_teachers GET    /admin/teachers(.:format)          admin/teachers#index
                   POST   /admin/teachers(.:format)          admin/teachers#create
 new_admin_teacher GET    /admin/teachers/new(.:format)      admin/teachers#new
edit_admin_teacher GET    /admin/teachers/:id/edit(.:format) admin/teachers#edit
     admin_teacher GET    /admin/teachers/:id(.:format)      admin/teachers#show
                   PUT    /admin/teachers/:id(.:format)      admin/teachers#update
                   DELETE /admin/teachers/:id(.:format)      admin/teachers#destroy
    admin_students GET    /admin/students(.:format)          admin/students#index
                   POST   /admin/students(.:format)          admin/students#create
 new_admin_student GET    /admin/students/new(.:format)      admin/students#new
edit_admin_student GET    /admin/students/:id/edit(.:format) admin/students#edit
     admin_student GET    /admin/students/:id(.:format)      admin/students#show
                   PUT    /admin/students/:id(.:format)      admin/students#update
                   DELETE /admin/students/:id(.:format)      admin/students#destroy
     admin_lessons GET    /admin/lessons(.:format)           admin/lessons#index
                   POST   /admin/lessons(.:format)           admin/lessons#create
  new_admin_lesson GET    /admin/lessons/new(.:format)       admin/lessons#new
 edit_admin_lesson GET    /admin/lessons/:id/edit(.:format)  admin/lessons#edit
      admin_lesson GET    /admin/lessons/:id(.:format)       admin/lessons#show
                   PUT    /admin/lessons/:id(.:format)       admin/lessons#update
                   DELETE /admin/lessons/:id(.:format)       admin/lessons#destroy
```

The problem is, i can't figure out how to respond a request to admin/students#update? I know how to respond to admin#teachers, in my admin controller i create a teachers function. But how to respond to admin/teachers/index? Or maybe where to respond? In which file? In which function or class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `admin/students#update` Rails will look for the action here:

```
class Admin::StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    # update here
  end
end
```

You can generate this file with:

```
rails generate controller admin/students update
```

Which will write to:

```
app/controllers/admin/students_controller.rb
```

Comment: is there a generator for this? and where should i put this in a new file?